# Python поиск последнего файла в папке

Tags: python-3.x

Код работает в Windows, при попытке выполнить в Docker контейнере выдает ошибку

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

def lastvideofile():
    p = Path(r'video')
    files=p.rglob('*.avi')
    latest_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)
    return latest_file

print(lastvideofile())
```

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, PosixPath found

понял что os.path.getctime() не подходит имя файла, но как подправить код чтоб и в Линуксе работало не понятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо просто преобразовать имя файла из типа `Path` в обычную строку.
Как вариант:

```
    latest_file = max(files, key=lambda f: os.path.getctime(str(f)))
```